Using Selenium with VBA to scrape data from website and running into issues with shadow DOM
This is my code:
Option Explicit

Private cd As Selenium.EdgeDriver

Sub Barchart()
    obj.Start "edge", ""
    obj.Get "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/gap/gap-up?viewName=main&orderBy=gapUpPercent&orderDir=desc"
    obj.Window.Maximize
    obj.Wait 2000

    Dim ShadowHost As Selenium.WebElement
    Set ShadowHost = obj.FindElementById("main-content-column")

    'Debug.Print ShadowHost.Attribute("id")

    ' Execute JavaScript code to access the shadow root of the Shadow DOM element
    Dim script As String
    script = "return arguments[0].shadowRoot;"
    Dim shadowRoot As Selenium.WebElement
    Set shadowRoot = obj.ExecuteScript(script, ShadowHost)

    Dim innerElement As Selenium.WebElement
    Set innerElement = shadowRoot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='_grid']/set-class[1]/div[2]/a/text-binding").Value
    MsgBox innerElement
End Sub

I was expecting to get a value returned, but I'm running into issues with not being able to find the elements.

"running into issues" could use a little more detail - what exactly happens when you run your code?
